# How can I download the exact uploaded file in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, download, jinja2

I was writing a code to download my file using a link which I have uploaded through the model in Django.

i.e in my **model.py**

```
class uploadFile(models.Model):
    id=models.CharField("Book id ",max_length=200,null=True,default="")
    name=models.CharField("Book name",max_length=200,null=True,default="")
    file=models.FileField(upload_to="media/ebooks")
```

and in my **view.py** I have 2 functions

```
def getdata(request):
    books=uploadFile.objects.all()
    n=len(QPapers)
    print("hello",QPapers)
    params={'QPapr':QPapers,'total_items':n}
    return render(request,'index.html',params)

def getdata2(request,nameparam):
    books=uploadFile.objects.all().filter(name=nameparam)
    n=len(QPapers)
    print("hello",QPapers)
    params={'QPapr':QPapers,'total_items':n}
    return render(request,'index.html',params)
```

and in **index.html**

```
 <a href="{% 'getdata' %}" download>download1</a>
```

for this urls.py is      `path('getdata',views.pdfNotes,name='pdfNotes'),`

here the file downloads correctly using above code
but when i am using the below code and calls to 2nd function with the name of book then instead of downloading file i have uploaded it downloads the `index.html` page.

```
<a href="{% 'getdata2' 'book1' %}" download>download2</a>
```

for this urls.py is     `path('getdata2/<str:name>/',views.pdfNotes,name='pdfNotes'),`

Is it because of filter I am using, or is the problem somewhere else?
I want to be download the specific file also that's why I am using the filter here...

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parameter of your view is `nameparam`, not <s>`name`</s>, you thus specify this in the URL patterns with:

```
#                      ↓ not name
path('getdata2/<str:nameparam>/',views.pdfNotes,name='pdfNotes'),
```

Comment: sry ,i have corrected that 'paramname'... that was leading to url error, but the issue is with downloading the file, it still downloading the .html page instead of doc file... can u please suggest any solution for that too. thank you willem...

Comment: @AshwinBehera: but all your views render an HTML file, hence in both cases, it will download the rendered HTML file, not some file stored in the storage.

Comment: To download files, you should *not* make use of Django, but work with an nginx/Apache/... server, since likely Django can not do this effeciently or safely.

Comment: @AshwinBehera: see the [*serving files* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files) of the documentation for more details.

Comment: in first function it downloads the stored file... i have tried to download other stored files too by making other function. but when i use this filter in second function then only it downloads the .html file. I don't why?

Comment: @AshwinBehera: because the view returns a HTTP response with HTML as content-type and with the content as response. Hence where you should it obtain the file stream from? The first function does not download the file either. If you really trigger that view, it will download a HTML file as well.